# Material UI AppBar not using theme colours

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI v4.7.0.

I have created a theme (see below) using `createMuiTheme()` with primary and secondary custom colours set.

I have an AppBar (see below). When I set the `color` on this to default, and toggle the theme, it only changes between black and white!

If I set `color="primary"`, it only shows in the `main` primary colour. This is even the case if I specify `light` and `dark` colours in the primary palette (This is how I know the theme is importing correctly).

It just will not change by theme!

Not only that, the background colours on the body tag and the Paper component are also only ever shades of black or white (depending on theme).

The docs (https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/) are absolutely useless!

Can someone please help with how I can set the theme for my app and have MUI **actually** use it?

Here is the NavBar code (assume the imports are all there, they are):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    logo: {
        height: getToolbarLogoHeight()
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            display: 'none',
        },
    }
}));

const NavBar = () => {
    const theme = useTheme();

    const { isAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const classes = useStyles();
    const Logo = theme.palette.type === 'light' ? LogoLight : LogoDark;

    console.log(theme);

    return (
        <AppBar position="sticky" color="default" className={classes.root}>
            <Toolbar>
                <IconButton className={classes.menuButton}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars}/>
                </IconButton>

                <Link to="/" style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                    <img alt="logo" src={Logo} className={classes.logo}/>
                </Link>

                {
                    isAuthenticated &&
                    <TopLinks/>
                }
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    );
};

export default NavBar;
```

And here is my theme:

```
export const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#2c3c52'
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#94c93d'
        },
        type: 'dark'
    }
});

export const getToolbarLogoHeight = () => {
    return theme.mixins.toolbar.minHeight - 10;
};

export default theme;
```

Comment: Not sure what does `actually use` mean? For example when you toggle to light, what color should AppBar be? What if toggle to dark?

Comment: The docs state (in the link above) that when creating a custom palette, MUI will automatically set a 'dark' and a 'light' colour off of that provided 'main' colour

Comment: I mean, when setting `AppBar color="primary"`, is your expectations: `toggle light => using primary.light; toggle dark => using primary.dark`, and reality: `toggle light/dark => both using primary.main`?

Comment: I've checked the source code, AppBar's colors are controlled like below, so in short: it only changes between `defaultBackgroundColor, primary.main, secondary.main` be design, unless you specifically control the colors of it. Code in next comment.

Comment: ```
    // Styles applied to the root element if `color="default"`
    colorDefault: {
      backgroundColor: backgroundColorDefault,
      color: theme.palette.getContrastText(backgroundColorDefault),
    },
    // if `color="primary"`
    colorPrimary: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
      color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
    },
    // if `color="secondary"`
    colorSecondary: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
      color: theme.palette.secondary.contrastText,
    },
```

Comment: F__k I cant fix the display, anyway I hope it helps

Comment: So how am I supposed to change the background of anything from light to dark mode? Or is this only for text? If so, this is rubbish!

Comment: I'll add my thought in the answer, but I cannot make a fully working sample right now

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to make your own AppBar component. I'm writing this using the component style but not the hook style.

In the `styles` you need

```
const styles = theme => ({
  lightMode: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
    color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
  }
  darkMode: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
    color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
  }
});
```

Then wrap your AppBar with `withTheme` hoc, so you can access `theme` in this.props; then in `render()`

```
const { theme } = this.props;
return (
  <AppBarFromMui
    className={clsx(
      [classes.lightMode]: theme.palette.type ==='light',
      [classes.darkMode]: theme.palette.type ==='dark',
    )}
  >
    {children or something}
  </AppBarFromMui>
```

Comment: I'm sorry Marson, I cannot get this working either. I also don't understand what it is doing..

Comment: Its checking what theme has been chosen and assigns a class to Appbar accordingly. Works but has some syntax issues.

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon this, and after a while I realised you really have to set two types of palette colors for each theme - one for **white** and one for **dark** type - in order to make use of the Mui's automatic rendering theme.

See example in [Material UI doc's](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#default-values) and toggle between the "dark/light" button on top to see the different **Main** color values.
[GIF example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOBaG.gif)

To my understanding, it will always apply the **Main** value color, and as for the **Light/Dark** (of the palette colors) purpose is more for ad-hoc solutions where the developer wants to customise a specific component or element as in [Mason Mao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59103195/4214043).
So to sum things up: **dark/light palette colors** are not directly linked to **dark/light theming**.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways in which I could make it work:

The first one is using the SX (SX={{bgcolor: 'someColor'}} prop on the Appbar (see: https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/).

The second one is through the theme, I could only make it look as I want in 'light' mode without any issue. For darkmode, I found out there's a prop which you need to pass to the Appbar in order to overwrite the default dark mode theme color palette (that prop is `enableColorOnDark` see here: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/app-bar/